# JFileChooser not returning the file name to main method

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

I am pretty new to Swing and AWT. Though I have experience in Java development. I am trying to read a file using JFileChooser and get the contents in my main method. All the gurus of Swing and AWT please help me identify what am I missing.

Here my code:

```
package com.ui;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class HomeScreen extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7604272718213756686L;

    String fileContent;
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    public HomeScreen()
    {
        super("Home Screen");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        // Button to open file
        final JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
        button.addActionListener
        (
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    int ret = fc.showDialog(button.getParent(), "Open");
                    if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    {
                        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
                         BufferedReader br;
                        try {
                            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                            String st ="";
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            while((st=br.readLine())!=null)
                            {
                                sb.append(st);
                            }
                            fileContent = sb.toString();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile()+" _____________________");
        add(button);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HomeScreen screen = new HomeScreen();
    }
}
```

This prints `null___________________________` even if I select a file with a lot of content.

Comment: Your `System.out` statement is triggered before you actually enter your `ActionListener`. Move that code to the end of the `actionPerformed` method and it will be solved

Answer (score 2):

Your `System.out.println()` statement is not in the appropriate code-block. You put it in your UI-initialization method (here it is your constructor) instead of within the `actionPerformed` method.

Now, there are a few additional things to take into consideration:

- All operations related to Swing must be done in the EDT (e.g. using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`)
- `JFrame.setVisible(true)` should be the last statement of your UI-initialization code
- If you load large files, you should consider moving the loading of the file to another thread than the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) in order to avoid GUI-freeze (`SwingWorker` is usually helpful for that)

Here is an updated version of your code (I added a textarea to display the loaded content):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HomeScreen extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7604272718213756686L;

    String fileContent;
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public HomeScreen() {
        super("Home Screen");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        // Button to open file
        final JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int ret = fc.showDialog(button.getParent(), "Open");
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile() + " _____________________");
                    BufferedReader br;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                        String st = "";
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(st);
                        }
                        fileContent = sb.toString();
                        textArea.setText(fileContent);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        textArea = new JTextArea(24, 40);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HomeScreen screen = new HomeScreen();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your effort. I am not sure if I was able to make the problem statement clear. I want the file content to be available to my main method so that I can use it for further processing. This is still not getting through .  :( I think I am not able to understand Swing.

Comment: @dharam Whatever you are trying to perform in your `main` method after getting the file should be moved into another method (like `protected void process(File file)`) and the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` you call that method after the user has selected a file: `process(fc.getSelectedFile());`. Swing is asynchronous, so you can't achieve synchronous behaviour within your main method (you could by using a modal `JDialog` but it still requires to be executed on the EDT).

Comment: oh! the statement "Swing is asynchronous" really helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new class variable called `File selectedFile`. You'r using your `FileChooser` in an `ActionListener` and is instatiated in this `Listener`, so you can't get a filename from there, you have to save the selected file into the class variable called `selectedFile`.

EDIT:
You can handle it via a Abstract Action:

```
public class FileChooserAction extends AbstractAction
{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser;
    int result = fc.showDialog(...);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
      System.out.println(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }
}
```

And then add a new Action (setAction() method of the button) to the button:

```
setAction(new FileChooserAction());
```

Comment: can you please elaborate. I am using it from actionlistener, I understand. But if I need to open the dialog on a click of a button , how do I do without using it from inside an actionlistener

Comment: You can set an AbstractAction to this button. I show you in the comment in a few minutes.